# Why wont my dell inspiron broadcom 1350 mini wifi adapter not connect to my wifi?

Tags: wireless, dell, inspiron

So I put Ubuntu on my dell inspiron recently and it will keep changing the wifi tick mark back to do not use when I click to tell it to use the device. Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I service more Dell laptops than any other brand, and I probably also encounter more Broadcom WIFI adapters than any other brand.  I recently responded to another question here, essentially the same as yours but regarding a different Broadcom device.  Though my comments there did not represent the necessary advice that user needed, I'm hoping [this pointer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528298/lubuntu-wireless-driver-for-bcm4309-14e44324-rev-02/528302?noredirect=1#comment721142_528302) to that thread will help you today.