# Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS doesn't detect Broadcom BCM4312 Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 14.4 LTS on 32-bit Dell Inspiron 1545 (that was actually pre-packaged with Ubuntu 10.x in about 2010).

For some reason, it doesn't have the capacity to scan for nearby wi-fi network.

I tried adding wi-fi network manually, but Ubuntu still acts as if it doesn't know about wireless

[image]

When I try executing:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

I get error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

## Requested information

```
sonihal@sonihal-Inspiron-1545:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" to your post.

Comment: For the dpkg lock issue see http://askubuntu.com/q/15433/178596

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/55868/178596 http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/178596

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have a wired connection. Then install the driver this way.
But close all programs before that. Like Synaptic or others.
Or just reboot. Some program is blocking installation.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

Wi-Fi should work.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this.

I completed all of the above, including this post:

[Lubuntu Wireless Driver for BCM4309 [14e4:4324] (rev 02)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528298/lubuntu-wireless-driver-for-bcm4309-14e44324-rev-02/528302?noredirect=1#comment721142_528302)

After installing the bcm drivers my wifi was working - i.e. I could see a list of available SSID's, but just not mine. I tried adding mine manually, but that didn't work, just like above.

My last thought was my router maybe didn't allow ipv6 and that I should disable it on 14.04. But then.. I was about to give up and head back to 12.04 and I came across this post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110

Following this, and rebooting (go figure), allowed me to see my SSID and connect.

I am a noob, so please be gentle if it was a bad idea to let people know here. And that thread is closed so I couldn't say thank you to chili555.